# Missing semicolon: C++ or SWIG issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, swig

This question is actually about SWIG, not a basic C++ missing a semicolon.

I have the following method in a class (in the header file):

```
class BarClass 
{
    // ... more code goes here
    unsigned int foo(unsigned int val) throw(std::invalid_argument) override;
    // ... more code goes here
};
```

I have a SWIG interface declaration in the form:

```
%include "stdint.i"
%include "std_except.i"
%include "exception.i"

%module mymodule
%{
    #include "headerFile.h"
%}
%include "headerFile.h"
```

The code is used as a C++ static library but also exposed to python via SWIG. Normal compilation with GCC / Clang works well.

However, when wrapping the library with SWIG, I receive an error:

> headerFile.h:22: Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.

I could replace the method declaration with:

```
unsigned int foo(unsigned int val) throw(std::invalid_argument);
```

When removing the override, SWIG seems to work but I get warnings. I have the impression that SWIG gets confused by the combination of throw and override at the same time.

Is this is SWIG bug or something silly that I am missing?

**Note:** I very much aware that using throw declarations is deprecated but that is the way SWIG gets information about exceptions and generates the appropriate code for Python. Maybe there is a better/newer way to do this in SWIG?

Comment: Is your class missing a `;` real or a typo?

Comment: typo.. sorry, I tried to concentrate on the real problem and missed that in the question

Comment: Those `...` aren't valid, either. Present your actual [MCVE], not some made-up nonsense that doesn't represent the problematic code.

Comment: @purpletentacle The we really need a [mcve].

Comment: It's _probably_ lack of support for `override`, though — try removing things until it works.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that was a bit harsh... SWIG requires a much more complicated build process that would not fit in the question. The issue is the relation between override and throw when compiled with SWIG

Comment: It's not "harsh". You've been here long enough to know to post a MCVE from the outset.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Maybe someone that has more experience with SWIG knows a bit more about the problem. It is definitely not about override.

Comment: btw, dynamic exception specifications are not allowed since C++17

Comment: How do you know the problem isn't in `// ... more code goes here`?

Comment: @bolov that is why I wrote the node. SWIG uses that to expose exceptions to python.

Comment: @interjay Because I have CI and can compile the exact code in OSX and Linux (both clang and gcc). Only when this class is wrapped by SWIG is when I see this compilation issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of how you know the problem isn't in the code which you chose not to show here.

Comment: @interjay I will update with more info

Comment: There's no need to %include "std_except.i" before %include "headerFile.h" right?

Comment: @TimSmit updated. My *.i is actually quite complicated.

Comment: Your header file doesn't even *have* 22 lines, unless your error message didn't come from your [mcve].  Please post *exactly* a complete minimal program and its *matching* error messages.

Comment: What version of SWIG are you using, and what command line are you using with swig to generate the wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are using SWIG with C++11:

http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html

7.2.11 Explicit overrides and final:  The special identifiers final and override can be used on methods and destructors, such as in the following example:

```
  virtual void ef() final override;
  virtual ~DerivedStruct() override;
```

You may either:

1. Use C++11 with the C++ compiler (eg: `-std=c++11`). **Recommended**
2. Disable (remove) C++11 features in code for SWIG's generator.
3. Use trick `#define override` to make the keyword `override` as a NO-OP.

Comment: can you elaborate your solutions?
1. Do you mean by this i have to compile my c++ lib as c++11 lib, or do you mean toggeling something during swig gerneation to c++ 11? Couldn't figure this one out

2. Whats the c++11 code genrator and how to turn it off?!

3. i assume this is solution specific for what swig can't process, but where to put the #define statement?